# How to get bytecode from several .py files?

Tags: python, bytecode

I am new to programming, working on a project to explore bytecode for Python. I have several python files with .py extensions and would like to use the `dis.dis()` function to save the bytecode equivalent of a lot of small programs.

For example, the code below, when run, will return the bytecode of the function (what's in the `def` part). My problem is that I cannot find a solution to import the files as text/code, for all the functions they define, and run this code over thousands of examples.

```
import dis

def something():
    n = int(raw_input())

    if n % 2 == 0:
        print (n, "is even")
    else:
        print (n, "is odd")

dis.dis(something)
```

Does anyone have any solution? I would like a loop or something similar which pulls in the .py files as text, pastes it to the def and than runs the code, saves the result. I can figure out the running and saving part, I just couldn't find anything which "pastes" the code from a .py file as it is, within the `def`.

**Update**

Based on the advice (thank you very much!), I have tried the below code. I used other StackOverFlow questions and answers and tried to resolve the issue. The code runs without error, even the last print statement is executed, and pyc files are generated, however, I am having trouble capturing the `dis.dis(code_obj, file=out)` output, it doesn't even print or save. Would you have any suggestions on where I have gone wrong?

```
import py_compile
from os import walk

# Define the path to compile from
mypath = 'C:/mydirectorycomeshere/SourceCodeChecker/'

# Assign the list of filenames in the mypath folder
f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mypath):
    f.extend(filenames)
    break
print('List read')

# Compile all files to pyc
py_compile.main(filenames)

# Define the path where these will be compiled
comppath = 'C:/mydirectorycomeshere/__pycache__/'

# Create new list with compiled files
f2 = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(comppath):
    f2.extend(comppath)
    break
print('Compiled list ready')

# Create bytecode from complied files and save them

import marshal, sys
import dis
import os
from io import StringIO

folderpath = r'C:/mydirectorycomeshere/__pycache__/'
filepaths = [os.path.join(folderpath, name) for name in os.listdir(folderpath)]
all_files = []

# Set header for marshal read of pyc files based on version

header_size = 8
if sys.version_info >= (3, 6):
    header_size = 12
if sys.version_info >= (3, 7):
    header_size = 16
print('Header set up ready')

# Iterate through compiled files and save or print output

import glob
for filename in glob.glob('*.pyc'):
   with open(os.path.join(os.cwd(), filename), 'r') as f:
       metadata = f3.read(header_size)
       code_obj = marshal.load(f3)
       with StringIO() as out:
           dis.dis(code_obj, file=out)
           print(out.getvalue())
           file.write(out)
       file = f.readlines()
       all_files.append(file)
print('Program ready')
```

Comment: Use `os.walk()` or `glob.glob()` to enumerate files, `compile()` to turn them into bytecode and `dis.dis()` to disassemble them.

Comment: Thank you @AKX, I will try end let you know the results. Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Are you using python 3.* or 2.7?

Comment: @12944qwerty, I am using Python 3.8.

Comment: FYI, `def`s define *functions*, not modules. In Python every .py script is technically a module.

Comment: Thank you @martineau, I was a bit lost there with the wording.

Comment: If you are using python 3.8, you cannot use `raw_input`. It was renamed to `input`

Comment: Thank you @12944qwerty, nice catch. Bytecode still compiles with it, so I will look into this more. I am also working on the full solution with the help of other StackOverFlow comments and will post the full code once I manage to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution with the help of my supervisor. This doesn't account for special circumstances, such as a space in the filename, but does solve the problem by saving the bytecode in `.txt` files:

```
from os import walk
import glob
import os
# Define the path to compile from
mypath = 'C:/yourfoldercomeshere/'

# Assign the list of filenames in the mypath folder
f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mypath):
    f.extend(filenames)
    break
print(filenames)
#Iterate through files, dis them and save them:

for filenames in glob.glob('*.py'):
      outfilename = filenames.replace('py', 'txt')
      print(outfilename)
      filenames=("python -m dis {0} > {1}".format(filenames,outfilename))
      os.system(filenames)
print(outfilename)
```